# Represent extreme values on Doughnut chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, charts, highcharts

I have created a report in SSRS and have represented the data on a scattered doughnut chart.

There are two series on the chart. Name of two series is 'Complete' and 'Incomplete'.

The values in 'Incomplete' series are very very small as compared to 'Complete' and are not seen in the chart.

For example if 'Complete' count is 5000 and 'Incomplete' is just 4 I cannot see it on the chart.

I understand I have to do something with axis/scale, but do any of you have any idea what exactly needs to be done in the chart to incorporate both the extreme values.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Scattered Doughnut?  do you mean Exploded Doughnut?

Comment: If your numbers are going to be as varied as 5,000 vs 4, truly the best way to represent this is by simply displaying the numbers as text. Any method that makes the chart look better is going to skew and misrepresent the data.

Comment: Yes I meant Exploded Doughnut

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Doughnut chart you're kind of stuck with the layout it gives you.  It's not possible to use logarithmic scaling for a Doughnut Chart for example.

You best bet for clarity is to set "Show Data Labels" to True.  You can then set the Series Label Data to be something like

```
=Fields!Status.Value & " = " & Fields!Val.Value
```

Resulting in the following Chart

[image]

Comment: Logarithmic Scale count by default starts from 10, hence I think I am not able to see this value "4". Also for doughnut chart I am not sure from where do we change the Logarithm scale value?

Comment: As I note above "It's not possible to use logarithmic scaling for a Doughnut Chart".  And the minimum value for a logarithmic Chart is 1 (As Log(0) = 1), it uses base 10 as default.